# How to get a Method instance for call stack element *without* arg signature?

Tags: java

*Disclaimer: I have 10 years' experience programming, but 8 of which is in PHP (loosely typed) -- I have been using Java now for 4 days* :)

In java, I need to get the value of an annotation for a method in the call stack. As far as I can tell, I do this with the Method object. From the call stack, I have retrieved the names of the class and method (strings). This is the (abbreviated) code that I am using...

**Calling Method:**

```
public class myClass
{
   @Path( "some/path/value" )
   public void myMethod( String someArg ) { ... }
}
```

**Retrieval Code:**

```
StackTraceElement[] trace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
String callingMethodName = trace[depth].getMethodName();
String callingClassName = trace[depth].getClassName();

Class[] signature = new Class[1];
signature[0] = String.class;

Class callingClass = Class.forName( callingClassName );
Method callingMethod = callingClass.getMethod( callingMethodName, signature );
Path annotation = callingMethod.getAnnotation( Path.class );
```

This works like a charm, successfully returning the value of the @Path annotation (`"some/path/value"`)

However, if you notice, I had to supply a signature of the method I was looking for. As you can see in the class code, there is only 1 method with that name, so, theoretically, the signature of the method should be irrelevant, right? As far as I can tell from various docs/blogs/examples, I should be able to call `getMethod( )` with either no 2nd argument, or with `null` for the 2nd argument, but if I use the following:

```
Class callingClass = Class.forName( callingClassName );
Method callingMethod = callingClass.getMethod( callingMethodName );
```

Or even:

```
Class callingClass = Class.forName( callingClassName );
Method callingMethod = callingClass.getMethod( callingMethodName, null );
```

I get a `NoSuchMethodException`. Am I doing something wrong here? Should I be taking a different approach altogether?

In this particular situation, the calling class/method never uses polymorphism so there is only ever 1 signature. However, said signature is not known (unless that can also be determined by data available/derivable from `Thread.currentThread( )`), so I need a way to get a Method object without knowing the signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The signature matters. If you don't know the exact signature, but know the name, get *all* the methods and iterate over them until you get a hit:

```
Method method = null;
for (Method m : c.getDeclaredMethods()) {
    if (m.getName().equals(callingMethodName)) {
        method = m;
        break;
    }
}
// variable "method" is the first that matched name, or null if not found
```

Also, since java 1.5, [`Class.getMethod(String, Class...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29) is a *varargs* method, so you don't need the java cruft that both the question and other answer has, ie:

#### This works, but avoid this crap (the old, hard way):

```
Class[] signature = new Class[1];
signature[0] = String.class;
Method callingMethod = callingClass.getMethod( callingMethodName, signature);
```

#### Prefer this (new way):

```
Method callingMethod = callingClass.getMethod( callingMethodName, String.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match on the method name (without worrying about the arguments), you can do something like the following:

```
...
private Method findMethod (Class cls, String name)
{
    for (Method method : cls.getDeclaredMethods( ))
        if (method.getName( ).equals(name))
            return method;
}
...
Method callingMethod = findMethod (callingClass, "myMethod");
Path annotation = callingMethod.getAnnotation(Path.class);
...
```

Basically just a linear search over all the methods in the class of interest until you find one with the name you're after.

Comment: Thanks for this! You and Bohemian gave basically the same answer, but I chose his because he gave more info.

Answer (score 0):

your code:

```
Method callingMethod = callingClass.getMethod( callingMethodName, null );
```

is looking for a method named `callingMethodName` which takes no arguments.  There's no magic that allows `getMethod` to figure out that your calls should return the *first* or *only* method with that name.  They retrieve the method that matches *exactly* what you're asking for.

otherwise, you'd have to use `.getMethods()` and iterate over them to find the one you want?